# What is best practice for a sceduled product import from csv files?

Tags: product, import

It would run every night and read a local csv file (an export from the ERP). It should have the following features:

- Two languages/storeviews
- Update attributes, product names, images, categories, tire prices, stock
- Delete products that are not in the csv any more
- Manage categories (create, update, delete)
- Manage attribute options (create, update, delete)
- Capable to update >5000 products in a reasonable time (at least before sunrise, better in less than an hour)

Three years ago I ended up writing a handcrafted script that keeps track of all current values, does some direct db-updates, loads/saves the complete product where necessary and has its own logic for category and attribute option management.

Is there a better way today? Maybe using [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page), the (since then enhanced) Magento Dataflow, or just by using different models in a still handcrafted script (like `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(...);` which would help with the attributes but not with names, images, tire prices etc.)

Comment: Have you taken a look at uRapidflow Pro?  It will handle both data types you mention and is pretty simple to setup a job via a bootstrap script and a crontab entry (they have notes on how jn their wiki)

Comment: @davidalger thanks for the hint – didn't know that tool. a bit pricy maybe. what are the advantages over magmi?

Comment: Having not used Magmi personally, I don't have anything I can offer on direct comparison. However, I've uRapidFlow Pro many times and it works very well. I have seen Magmi installed on sites we picked up from others leaving gaping security holes on the site, as well as many issues caused by using it since it's going straight to the db and may or may not get things 100% how they would be if objects were saved from the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only it was all that simple companies would not spend $10s to $100s thousands on Supplier Onboarding tools and ETL/ESB connectors. There is no business information, Magento CE or EE, website or global pricing, percentage of records changing per day, whether you have a separate admin/batch server, size of company either orders per day - visitors per day - revenue per year. All these affect the choice of the solution.

Now, if you are not interested in the business side and just want a technical solution you have Magmi, import scripts via API (with or without indexing switched on), or ETL tools (SaaS or in-house). The devil though is in the detail. An example, if you use API without index onsave you need to reindex, if you have too many stores or too many products on a high volume site, you have frontend issues. If you do not have a cluster this overloads the servers slowing performance, and if you have website pricing you need to perform multiple updates. For all intents and purposes Magmi is the API without index on save, just a lot faster. So if you have a high-volume site you use either EE or CE with index on save.

We have worked with sites with 100s stores and 100s thousands of products with website-pricing and automated data loading (the most complex of complex until the soft limit of Magento was hit, pushed passed it, and hit a hard limit) all the way down to the simplest store. If you are a single store (or in your case double) with single currency with 5,000 products then the API load script, Magmi and reindex, or CSV uploads will work just fine, any more and it all starts to become very complex the more you add, hence why we are under nda for the solutions as the high-end consultants who developed them are only a handful who have any idea how to bring all the pieces together (hosting, clusters, indexing, loading, delta records, data cleaning, data mapping).

Just stick with the script, you can enhance it with Magmi calls to their API so you get the best of both worlds, one of the solutions from the consultants did this, if it is working why change it.

Comment: thanks for the detailed overview! I consider changing it, because my current solution lacks of elegance and needs some improvements. So I'm trying to figure out what benefits I would have from a complete refactoring. I'll have a closer look to magmi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not hitting the Magmi Limitations (afaik no bundled and no downloadables, configurables with plugin (not tried it yet))  then Magmi is a very good solution, especially for huge catalogs.

A Model based approach seemt to lack speed, at least compared to more direct approaches.

Afaik [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) can do nearly everything you asked for in reasonable time and it is very customizable. (We are using it for ~10k products in round about 20 minutes). Afaik it only lacks attribute management support.

Comment: Thanks for this hint also ... didn't know the AvS_FastSimpleImport. How does it compare with Magmi?

Comment: Not used Magmi in a long time. Last time i used it the import of configurable products was impossible so i had to look for something else because that project had about 60% of its products as configurables.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is definitely Magmi.

All you need is to write a [custom script](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API) and add it to cron tab on your server.

It's the best because:
1) it uses direct SQL queries in order to insert/update products data rather than Magento php classes so it works **much faster**
2) **all** features you listed are supported out of box. You just need to configure it properly
3) you can easily use MAGMI inside your custom php cron script where you can do all you want (check the link above)
4) the documentation is much better than docs for Magento standard ways (check the link above)

Comment: instead of simply saying Magmi is the best way in your answer, it might help folks more if you elaborated and explained why it would be best for the OPs scenario.

Comment: @davidalger you're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Serpyre I still insist that all listed by OP features supported out of box with MAGMI :P Only need to install the required plugins. As for mapping - it's clear from the question that OP is ok to deal with code, so I guess a simple custom php mapper is not a big deal. However even the case which you referred to (D&G -> Dolce & Gabbana) is actually possible in MAGMI withot any coding: see here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Value_Replacer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the best way is to write a custom import module. The Dataflow profiles are terribly slow and inefficient. As is processing product updates / creates one csv row at a time. You'll get performance enhancement by digesting multiple ( say 100 ) rows at once, looping through an array and using PHP's clone $var functionality on a catalog/product module instantiated in some classes constructor.

We've got an exceptional data import we spent about 2000 hours building, if you've got a budget I'd be willing to set it up for ya!